# Set CaptiveInfo on Carbon Copy recipient

Tags: docusignapi, carbon-copy

I am creating and sending an envelope using the SOAP method “CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms”. Is it possible to set the CapitveInfo (ClientUserId and EmbeddedRecipientStartURL) on a Carbon Copy type recipient. When attempting to do this on my current setup, i get the error: "A carbon copy recipient has been specified as captive.  This operation is not supported". Is there a setting i can change or a different method i can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a Captive Carbon-Copy type Recipient. Carbon-Copy Recipients can only be Remote (email delivery). [DocuSign SOAP API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/Supressed%20Features%20and%20Behaviors.htm)

It is possible however, to have a Captive Certified Delivery type Recipient. This may be a suitable workaround depending on your scenario. The possible catch when using this type of Recipient is that the Recipient needs to view the envelope documents (at least render the URL) before the workflow can continue.